# Turn timestamp (chr) to only year and month (date)?

Tags: r, date

I have a timestamp column that was imported automatically as factor instead of date.It is like this:

```
    timestamp  
2015-03-22 00:08:15
2015-03-22 00:08:15
2015-03-22 00:08:21
2015-03-22 00:08:45
2015-03-22 00:08:56
2015-03-22 00:08:59
```

i have to keep only the year and month and did this:

```
df$timestamp<-format(as.Date(df$timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y-%m")
```

and it turned out fine but the problem is that the type is `chr` although i used as date.

Also i did another column :

```
df$arrival_date<- format(as.Date(w$arrival_date, format = "%Y-%m"))
```

and it is again `chr`

How to make it a date?

Comment: Because you are using `format`, it converts to `character`  The `as.Date` is enough for 'Date' class.  and date class have a specific format.  If you need to `yearmonth` format try `as.yearmon` from `zoo` on the `as.Date` i.e. `as.yearmon(as.Date(....`

Comment: So you can't do that with as.Date at all?The class it creates with the zoo is not date though.